# Find Value in Array

Tags: php

The following array is output from my db.

```
$this->db->select('code')->from('table');
$array = $this->db->get()->result_array();

//Output:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => ASDF123 ) [1] => Array ( [code] => ASDF124 ) )
```

How can I find if a variable is contained in this array?

ie.

```
if(this_is_in_array($value, $array) == TRUE)...
```

What's the simplest way to to that with PHP?

**I sincerely apologize for not wording this correctly the first time.**

Comment: You should consider rephrasing your question. It is unfortunately terribly hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, please rephrase your question.

Comment: Yes, it did actually. Wonderful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you wish to find the KEY of an array you would refer to the `array_key_exists()` method.
An example of this would be:

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2'
);

if ( array_key_exists( 'key2', $array ) )
    return TRUE;
```

If you would however prefer to find the VALUE of an array, you would refer to the `in_array()` method. An example of this would be:

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2'
);

if ( in_array( 'value1', $array ) )
    return TRUE;
```

**Kevin:**

```
foreach( $array as $key => $values )
{
    if ( $values['code'] == 'ASD1234' )
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, Chris.  What do I do if my array looks dumb like this: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => ASDF123 ) [1] => Array ( [code] => ASDF124 ) )`  That's what my db is spitting at me.

Comment: I'm still uncertain exactly what part you are trying to access/compare something with. If you are trying to fetch the actual code value of each element, you could run a foreach and then do an if statement to check if the code is what it is supposed to be, exit or continue the loop on success.

Comment: I added an example described in my previous comment, so you could more easily understand it.

Comment: The `foreach` was what I was looking for.

Comment: Brilliant! Glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 2):

make your array this:

```
$your_array = array('key1'=>'value1', 'key2'=>'value2');
```

then use this to see if the key exists in the array.

```
if (array_key_exists('key2', $your_array)) {
```

Comment: the array in my example is output from the db...can I manipulate it into a more usable array?

Comment: Also, I believe I meant to find a value, not the key...I'm sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Unsure about what exactly you mean in your question, however, to answer your question title, you can use the `array_key_exists()` function to check if a given key or index exists within an array.

Comment: Would you please show me with my specific array?  I'm a noob.

Comment: Being a noob isn't an excuse for not at least [checking the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) for how to use it...

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. But, I'm unclear if you want to check if a `key` is in the array or is it the `value` you're after ?

Comment: In that case you can test if a value is in an array using the `in_array` function.

Answer (score 1):

put your validation into the function

```
$input = 'ASDF123';

function check_input($input) {
    $array = array(
        0 => array('code' => 'ASDF123'),
        1 => array('code' => 'ASDF124')
    );
    foreach ($array as $codes) {
        if (in_array($input, $codes)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$needle = 'ASDF123';
$ary = Array(
  Array('code' => 'ASDF123'),
  Array('code' => 'ASDF124')
);
$_ = "return (\$a['code']='".addslashes($needle)."');";
if (count(array_filter($ary[0],create_function('$a',$_))) > 0)
  //true
```

**I THINK** (only because you use `code` twice, so I assume that's not the search field--or it's a semantics issue). If it is semantics, as everyone else has already suggested, try [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).