# PHP explode - running loop through each array item

Tags: php, loops, explode

Here's the issue:

I retrieve the following data string from my database:

```
$row->exceptions = '1,2,3';
```

After `explode` I need the below code to check each one of the exploded pieces

```
$exceptions = explode(",", $row->exceptions);

//result is 
//[0] => 1
//[1] => 2
//[2] => 3

for ($i = 0; $i <= $row->frequency; $i++) {

    if ($exceptions[] == $i) {

        continue;

    } else {

        //do something else
    }
}
```

How can I make `$exceptions[]` loop through all keys from the exploded array so it evaluates if `==$i`?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find Value in Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703004/find-value-in-array)

Comment: not sure about that - here i am in need of a solution not to find a specific key, but to loop through all keys

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question, so I'm posting a comment: if I got it, it should suffice to substitute "if($exceptions[] == $i)" with "if(in_array($i,$exceptions))".

Comment: @paolo, that's an elegant solution and works nicely - would you mind posting it as answer? - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should suffice to substitute:

```
if($exceptions[] == $i)
```

with:

```
if(in_array($i,$exceptions))
```

By the way, it eliminates the need for a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, should be straightforward, no?

```
$exceptions = explode(",", $row->exceptions);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $row->frequency; $i++) {

    foreach($exceptions as $j){
    if($j == $i){
        // do something
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Glad to help: `in_array` is more elegant. No reason not to use the platform functions if they are available and fit the task.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking. Here's how you would test within that loop whether the key equals `$i`.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $row->frequency; $i++)
{
  foreach ($exceptions as $key => $value)
  {
    if ($key == $i)
    {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```