# mysql join one to many with images

Tags: mysql, sql, image, join

I have two tables...

**project table**

```
+----+--------+
| id | client |
+----+--------+
|  1 | James  |
|  2 | John   |
+----+--------+
```

**images table**

```
+----+-----------+-------------------+
| id | projectId |     imagePath     |
+----+-----------+-------------------+
|  1 |         1 | images/image1.jpg |
|  2 |         1 | images/image2.jpg |
|  3 |         2 | images/image3.jpg |
|  4 |         2 | images/image4.jpg |
|  5 |         2 | images/image5.jpg |
+----+-----------+-------------------+
```

As you can see, one project has many images. I want to display that 
this way...

```
James

images/img1.jpg
images/img2.jpg

John

images/img3.jpg
images/img4.jpg
images/img5.jpg
```

This post gave me what I want       https://stackoverflow.com/a/2451065/1214535

But when I echo like so

```
<img src='".$row['imagePath']."/>
```

the results in image tag I get this

```
<img src="images/img3.jpg,images/img4.jpg,images/img5.jpg">
```

instead of

```
<img src="images/img3.jpg"/> 
<img src="images/img4.jpg"/>
<img src="images/img5.jpg"/>
```

How can I change the query so that I can display the images properly/separately

this is the query I am using

```
$sql="SELECT images.projectId,project.client,
GROUP_CONCAT(images.imagePath SEPARATOR ', ') 
AS 'imagePath' 
from project left JOIN images on project.id=images.projectId 
GROUP BY project.id ASC";
```

thank you guys...

Comment: Depending on how large your table and result sets are, you're better off with the GROUP_CONCAT and explode() suggestion that people have made.

If you do the query without the GROUP_CONCAT, you'll get the overhead of fetching and sending the project and client data with every row. With the GROUP_CONCAT option, you don't get this overhead.

**However**, keep in mind that GROUP_CONCAT is limited to 1024 bytes by default. You can tune this by changing the group_concat_max_len option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `foreach` to loop through different values.

Syntax:

```
foreach (array_expression as $value)
    statement
```

First insert all the values you get in an array like this:

```
$imgArray = explode(',',$row['imagePath']);
```

Then loop through this array as:

```
foreach ($imgArray as $img)
{
 echo "<img src='$img'" />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks thanks guys for all your answers.Using explode and looping through did the trick.

Comment: i have question about fetching one image against one product like. One product has many (4) images but i only want to show only one image against that product.

Comment: @AliRaza In that case you don't have to loop over the list. Once you have the list of image as `$imgArray` is above example, select the image you want using the list index like `echo "<img src='$imgArray[0]'" />";`

Comment: sorry my question wasnt so clear, Want to show all the products in product table and also there images, but every product should show one image from image table. ( i use the inner join but inner join fetch all the image against one product, that is not what i want) if the question is not clear please do tell, ill try to explain further details. main thing is `All the products with only one image against each product`

Comment: This can be solved at the query level itself. if i got the question correctly, you can do this by using group by on product and take min/ max of id.

Answer (score 1):

you have to break the string like below

```
$imgArray = explode(',',$row['imagePath']);
//then do 
foreach($imgArray as $im)
{
 if( is_readable($im) ) {
         echo "<img src='$im' title='Image' />";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [EXPLODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is the answer.Look at [PHP explode - running loop through each array item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925800/php-explode-running-loop-through-each-array-item) Stack overflow question. I believe that it will answer to your question.

Also, I think (another approach) if you change ur query to

```
SELECT tp.CLIENT,ti.IMAGEPATH
FROM tblProject tp 
JOIN tblImage ti ON tp.Id = ti.ProjectId
```

then a simple loop will be easy to get you through.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which is returning all non-null values as string.

You can use below query:

```
$sql="SELECT images.projectId,project.client,images.imagePath SEPARATOR
AS 'imagePath'
from project left JOIN images on project.id=images.projectId 
GROUP BY project.id ASC";
```

And loop through result.

Comment: it is a good approach you use. but i have question about fetching one image against one product like. One product has many (4) images but i only want to show only one image against that product.